# How to override Done (node-dialog-ok) button on click event in node-red?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I'm currently having a custom node, which I've created.

What I need is, to do something when the `Done` **(id: node-dialog-ok)** button is clicked from the **editor-tray-toolbar** instead of the default functionalities.

Is it possible to override the `onclick` event of the button?

Or how could I use it in my favor, within my node itself if I'm to just print an `alert` when the `Done` button is being clicked? I'm still new to this, so please do bare, for me being obscure.

Any help could be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `oneditsave` call back in the node HTML file.

The docs for creating the HTML file are [here](http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/properties#custom-edit-behaviour)

> oneditsave: (function) called when the edit dialog is okayed. See custom edit behaviour.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType('node-type',{
        // node definition
        oneditsave: function() {
            ....
        }
    });
</script>
```